# SwiftUI DatePicker not selecting in sheet

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, calendar

Im using the native DatePicker in swiftUI presented through a sheet. The date picker it self is of graphical style. When the sheet is presented I can scroll through months but I cannot make a selection. To make a selection I have to constantly press on the date for 5-6 seconds. But if I use a wheel style everything works as expected. Im not sure if this is an iOS bug or something I am missing. Note: code works on preview_provider but not on actual device.

```
@State var showCalendar:Bool = false
@State var selectedDate:Date = Date()

.sheet(isPresented: $showCalendar){
    VStack{
       DatePicker("", selection: $selectedDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
                .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
       Spacer()
    }
}
```

Comment: This works fine for me running on an iPhone 14 Pro with iOS 16.2. Can you please supply a [mcve]

Comment: What DatePicker are you using where the selection is a boolean? ;)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson my mistake.. it was supposed to point to the sheet not the date.. Actual code is pointed correctly.. I'm editing the question now as problem still persists..